# How to get rid of exclamation mark of script this$.text();

Tags: function, object, push, var

**SAMPLE:**   - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/bYs4x/)

**This script:**

```
var slides = [];           
$("ul .image").each(function() {
    var this$ = $(this);
    var obj = {};
    obj.image = this$.text();

    slides.push(obj);
});

document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(slides);
```

**makes out of this html:**

```
<ul>
    <li><span class="image">/images/image1.jpg</span></li>
    <li><span class="image">/images/image2.jpg</span></li>
</ul>
```

**this output:**

```
[{"image":"/images/image1.jpg"},{"image":"/images/image2.jpg"}]
```

**How can i get rid of the exclamation marks around the** *"image":* **on every beginning before the colon?**

Thank you, Linda :)))

Edit:

The expected result is this:

```
     [
      {image:"/images/image1.jpg"},
      {image:"/images/image2.jpg"}
     ]
```

Comment: What exclamation marks?

Comment: Can you please show us what is your expected result? Thanks

Comment: I mean the exclamation marks around the word "image": before the colom.

I need this for a js slideshow called supersized. The script should help me to use "li" tags instead of typing all parts into the script itself...

Comment: @Linda89 check my reply

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XN6BQ/)

```
var slides = [];           
$("ul .image").each(function() {
    var this$ = $(this);
    var obj = {};
    obj.image = this$.text();
    obj.title = this$.nextAll(".title").text();
    obj.thumb = this$.nextAll(".thumb").text();
    slides.push(obj);
});

var str = JSON.stringify(slides);

document.body.innerHTML = str.replace(/"image"/g , "image");
```

Comment: thank you very much :) you are great, but i didn't get it to work in spiete of your perfect script

Comment: So, in this case, removing the double quotes (not exclamation mark like you said) is not helpful. Please tell me which value your application will accept then we will give you another answer if possible. Have a nice weekend :)